# Mongoose update document Fail with findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to update MongoDB document using findByIdAndUpdate:

```
var landmarkModel = mongoose.model('landmark', landmarkSchema, 'landmarks');  
var lm = new landmarkModel();

//adding data to schema here, like: lm.name = req.body.name;

lm.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, lm, function (err, landmark) {
    if (err)
       console.log(err);
    else{
       console.log(null, landmark);
    }
});
```

Error returned: `Object lm has no method 'findByIdAndUpdate'`

I have tried swapping out the `lm.findByIdAndUpdate` value with `landmarkModel.findByIdAndUpdate` but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findByIdAndUpdate` is a static method:

```
var landmarkModel = mongoose.model('landmark', landmarkSchema, 'landmarks');
var lm = req.body;

delete lm._id;

landmarkModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, lm, console.log);
```

Note that `landmarkModel` accepts plain `js` objects.

If you already have a `mongoose` object then it's best to use `save` instead:

```
var landmarkModel = mongoose.model('landmark', landmarkSchema, 'landmarks');

landmarkModel.findById(req.body._id, function (err, lm) {
  if (err) return next(err);

  //adding data to schema here, like: lm.name = req.body.name;

  lm.save(console.log);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after implementing your code: [Error: Invalid atomic update value for $__. Expected an object, received object]

Comment: Probably, you passing `Mongoose` object as an update to `findByIdAndUpdate`. In my example `lm` should be plain `js` object.

Comment: I converted `lm` to an object using `lm.toObject();` (I'm doing additonal server side modifications to the req.body) and now the console.log call back on `findbyIdAndUpdate` returns `null null` and the document was not updated

Comment: I recommend you to switch to `findById` = `save`. It was designed for your case.