# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a fairly straight forward method below to update a document based on its ObjectId.  It does not return an error but it fails to make the required updates to the document.  I think it is failing because, according to my research, findByIdAndUpdate() takes only plain Javascript whereas job._id is an ObjectId from the document that I want to update.  Can someone tell me how to make this work correctly?

```
function handleEncoderResponse(xmlResponse, job) {
var r = et.parse(xmlResponse);
var mediaID = r.findtext('./MediaID');
var message = r.findtext('./message');

EncodingJob = mongoose.model('EncodingJob');

EncodingJob.findByIdAndUpdate( job._id, {
    "MediaID": mediaID,
    "Status": message
}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});

}
```

Edit: Per this question [Mongoose update document Fail with findByIdAndUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191281/mongoose-update-document-fail-with-findbyidandupdate)

I also tried the following code to no avail.

```
job.MediaID = mediaID;
job.Status = message;
job.save(function(err, res) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    });
```

This approach yields the issue.  It does not update the document and it does not return an error.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, my mistake was forgetting to define `MediaID` and `Status` in the `Schema` as follows:

```
var encodingJobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    MediaID: String,
    Status: String
});
```